# How to alert the text someone writes in for example recipient/ message

Tags: javascript, dom, alert

I just started playing with DOM, and I am trying to do the following thing:
1.I created a form that has a recipient/ message and two buttons : submit/ reset;

```
<form id="event">
<!-- Recipient -->
Recipient <input type="text" required class="msg" > <br>

<!-- Message -->
<label for="message" >Message</label>

<textarea rows="4" cols="30" class="msg" > </textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset">
```

2. When I press submit, I want to send an alert with what I wrote in those two fields. The problem is that here I get stuck, I managed only to alert either the recipient or the message. Here's my code:

```
document.querySelector('#event').addEventListener('submit', function(a) {
```

a.preventDefault()
alert(a.target.elements.input.value)

})
Did I make this matter way too complex? I feel completely stuck at the moment, a tip would be amazing. Thanks in advance, wish you a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily the best way to do it, but it's working.

```js
document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const recipient = document.querySelector('[name="recipient"]').value;
  const message = document.querySelector('[name="message"]').value;
  window.alert(`${recipient}: ${message}`);
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="recipient">Recipient</label>
  <input type="text" required class="msg" name="recipient">
  <br>
  <label for="message">Message</label>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="30" class="msg" name="message"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

You may also learn how to select `name` attributes using this. It's always useful to know.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer! I realised after all that the huge problem was indeed the fact that I didint use a name for text area! Being a noob, I thought that the message from label was enough. As for the alert, here's how I did it in a shorter way :  alert(a.target.elements.recipient.value + " "+a.target.elements.message.value)    .. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score -1):

You to change the event listener to "click".

see example:
[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer! I managed to solve it by adding a name to my text area (i figured it out from your picture that i didnt do it, it wasnt enough to have a message only in the label)and using the code I initially wrote for the js part, but the alert written like this: alert(a.target.elements.recipient.value + " "+a.target.elements.message.value)